# Check if a matrix is Positive Semidefinite

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, algorithm

I have a question concerning the check whether a given matrix is positive semidefinite or not. In mathematica the function `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[m]` tells me whether the matrix `m` is positive, but not semidefinite. I wanted to ask whether there exists an implementation for that purpose, and if not, how to implement a code that is as fast as possible.

Comment: Is your matrix symbolic or numeric?

Comment: It is a 15x15 matrix simply consisting of integers.

Comment: You could compute the eigenvalues numerically to do the check---that is very fast.

Comment: Given its all integers, you can check exact roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 12):

Computing the eigenvalues is actually overkill. It could be done by row reduction. For convenience, I set empty list to be positive semidefinite.

```
psdcheck[m_]:=(
  If[Length@m== 0,Return@True];
  If[Length@m== 1,Return@If[Negative@m[[1,1]],False,True]];
  If[Or@@(Negative@Diagonal@m),Return@False];

  Module[{mtemp,ind1},
    mtemp=If[SymmetricMatrixQ@m,m,(#+Transpose@#)&@m];
    ind1=Flatten@Position[Diagonal@mtemp,diag_/;diag== 0.];

    If[Length@ind1!=0,
      If[(#!=ConstantArray[0.,Dimensions@#])&@(mtemp[[ind1]]),Return@False,
        mtemp=mtemp[[#,#]]&@Complement[Range@Length@mtemp,ind1];
        If[Length@mtemp<= 1,Return@psdcheck@mtemp]];];

  psdcheck[mtemp[[2;;,2;;]]-
    (Outer[Times,#,#/mtemp[[1,1]]])&@mtemp[[1,2;;]]]
])
```

Comment: Is `diag_/;diag== 0.` the same as `0.`?

Comment: Hi Hsien-Ching, good to see you are here too!

Comment: diag_/;diag==0 and 0. are different. Position uses pattern matching to identify the elements. 0. == 0 is True but 0. and 0 are different patterns.  Good to see you here too,  Sjoerd.

Comment: There are numerical issues with the code during the pivoting step. This could be avoided by choosing the largest diagonal element as pivot instead of blindly choosing the first one. Besides, the code only works on real case but it is easy to generalize it to the complex situation. One could further utilize the symmetric property (after symmetrization) to reduce the memory usage and the number of multiplications. This code is significantly faster than the method based on eigenvalue calculation.

Answer (score 7):

One can add a small addition:

```
semiPositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[m_, tol_: 10.^-10] := 
   PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[m + tol IdentityMatrix@Dimensions[m]]

PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ@{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}
semiPositiveDefiniteMatrixQ@{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

> False
>
> True

*Explanation:*

Let the matrix $M$ has $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots \lambda_n$ eigenvalues. Then the matrix $M+tI$ ($I$ is the identity matrix) has $\lambda_1+t, \lambda_2+t, \dots \lambda_n+t$ eigenvalues. If $M+tI$ is positive definite and $t>0$ is small enough (depends on the working precision) then $M$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: This should work as long as the entries in the matrix are all small. Otherwise... maybe not.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I think it should works for any matrices. See my update, do you agree with it?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear--mathematically I absolutely agree, but I was thinking about the case when the matrix entries are larger in absolute magnitude than `tol/$MachineEpsilon` (= 450 000 for the default tolerance). Then you effectively add the zero matrix (or at least not a full rank identity matrix), so the result will not (or may not) change. I am not sure how this situation can be rescued without resorting to calculating the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a function `PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ` that does this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that computes only the *smallest* eigenvalue and checks that it's greater or equal to zero. This can be done by using a shift as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44153/245), or for large matrices by using the option `Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}` for `Eigenvalues`:

```
Clear@positiveSemiDefiniteQ
positiveSemiDefiniteQ[mat_?MatrixQ] := (
       First@Eigenvalues[N[mat] + # IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[mat]], 
        1] - #) >= 0. &@Norm[Flatten[mat]]

positiveSemiDefiniteQ[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}]

(* ==> True *)
```

The `Arnoldi` method isn't usable for the small matrix in this example, so I decided to post this more general approach. The difference to the other `Eigenvalues` based solution is that I only need one eigenvalue, after I make the shift that guarantees that all eigenvalues are sorted properly.

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is numeric, the following should be a reasonably fast way to determine positive semi-definiteness:

```
Clear@positiveSemiDefiniteQ
positiveSemiDefiniteQ[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
    With[{eigs = Chop@Eigenvalues@N@mat},
        Quiet[
            Check[
                And @@ Thread[eigs >= 0],
                False,
                GreaterEqual::nord
            ],
            GreaterEqual::nord
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to check if the matrix is symmetric (Hermitian).  Usually positive definiteness is only defined for such matrices.

Comment: @Szabolcs Nope. Example: `{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that checks to see if the roots of the characteristic polynomial are all non-negative (as suggested by Daniel Lichtblau:

```
semiDefQ[m_] := Module[{p, roots},
   p[x_] := CharacteristicPolynomial[m, x];
   roots = Chop[Roots[p[z] == 0, z] // N];
   Length[Select[Apply[List, roots[[All, 2]]], # ∈ Reals && # >= 0 &]] == n]
```

To use, just input your favorite matrix

```
n = 3;
m = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {n, n}];
semiDefQ[m]
```