# Schrödinger eigenvalue problem in two dimensions (Harmonic Oscillator)

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I read [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32293/) the discussion about how to solve a one-dimensional eigenvalue problem. I am wondering, how can one generalize these methods to two dimensions?

For example, how to solve this equation:

$$-(d^2/dx^2+d^2/dy^2)u(x,y)+(x^2+y^2+xy)u(x,y)=Eu(x,y)$$

or any other potentials?

What about three dimensions? Is there any general procedure?

Comment: I am curious about, what can one obtain by coupling two harmonic oscillators, such a potential: x^2 + y^2 +xy? Is this solvable? I can find the ground state energy analytically, but I want to see the whole eigenstates and the corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, just rotate the coordinate system and the oscillators decouple (normal mode decomposition, works for any potential of degree 2).

Comment: Instead of de-coupling them, is it possible to solve it directly by Mathematica?

Comment: Yes, I have a version of my answer in the [question you linked](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32295/245) that applies to two dimensions. But it was written by a student in my class a few years ago, so I can't post it online. Anyway, this means the method works in 2D, only unfortunately quite slow because obviously the matrices are harder to construct and get much bigger.

Comment: Oh Lord! Bad luck!

Comment: Since *Mathematica* is quite good with the time-dependent Schrödinger equation, you could also use [one of the methods here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27842/245) and do a Fourier analysis of the time-dependent wave-packet evolution. That's another way of getting eigen-energies.

Comment: Actually, I went through your answer to the other question concerning propagation of wave packet. So, you mean that it is possible to obtain eigenfunctions and corresponding eigenvalues by the Fourier analysis of wave packet?

Comment: The potential that you have considered at that post and obtained the evolution of its wave packet, is periodic and vanishes at the box boundaries. I think the case here, is different. Am I wrong?

Comment: It all depends on what the actual potential looks like that you're interested in. I'd say the most generic answer is: use a spatial discretization, e.g., finite-difference scheme. Fourier analysis of a wave packet at fixed position over time in a binding potential gives you the energies of the eigenstates that are contained in the wave packet (due to their $exp(-iE t/\hbar)$ factors). It doesn't give you the eigenfunctions so directly.

Comment: If I focus on this potential: x^2+y^2+xy, you say that its eigenfunctions and corresponding eigenvalues, in principle, is obtainable by spatial discretization. If I want to go through the wave packet approach, is your solution to that question regarding wave packet, applicable for this potential? Because there, your potential was periodic and vanished at the box boundaries, but here is not.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In order to give one possible answer, I'll just take the isotropic harmonic oscillator in 2D and do a finite-difference calculation by discretizing the xy plane with constant spacing `a`.

Here is the construction of the resulting matrix for the Hamiltonian, `h`. I assume the origin of our spatial grid (where the potential minimum is) lies at `{0,0}`, and the number of grid points in all directions from the origin is `nX`. Each grid step corresponds to a length of `a = 0.2`. On this grid, I then define the potential energy as a function `v[x_, y_]`, and evaluate it at the grid points to create the 2D matrix `vGrid`. But this is the easy part.

Now we have to make a matrix out of the Hamiltonian in the space of *tuples* of `{x,y}` positions. This means the rows and columns of the matrix that we want to diagonalize are labeled by the entries of a list of tuples, which I call `xyList`. The Hamiltonian has one term that corresponds to the potential energy, and it is created in the above basis of tuples by taking the entries of the matrix `vGrid` corresponding to the tuple labeling each diagonal element of the Hamiltonian. This happens in the `DiagonalMatrix` term.

Finally, we have to construct the kinetic energy, i.e., the Laplacian. This is the only off-diagonal part of the matrix. *How* far off the diagonal its matrix elements extend depends on the *order* of the finite-difference approximation by which we replace the second derivatives in the Laplacian. Here I chose the simplest possible approximation.

```
nX = 20;
a = .2;

Clear[v];
v[x_, y_] := 1/2 (x^2 + y^2)

vGrid = Table[v[a i, a j], {i, -nX, nX}, {j, -nX, nX}];

xyList = Tuples[Range[1, 2 nX + 1], 2];

Timing[
 h = DiagonalMatrix[
     SparseArray[(vGrid[[##]] & @@@ xyList) + 2/a^2]] - 
    1/(2 a^2) AdjacencyMatrix[GridGraph[{2 nX + 1, 2 nX + 1}]];]

(* ==> {0.009491, Null} *)

v = Eigenvectors[h, -10];

ListDensityPlot[Partition[v[[10]], 2 nX + 1], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: ground state]

This is the ground state. The eigenvalues have near-degeneracies:

```
e = Eigenvalues[h, -10]

(*
==> {3.97742, 3.97742, 3.96769, 3.96769, 2.98745, 2.98244, \
2.98244, 1.99247, 1.99247, 0.997494}
*)
```

The exact values of the energy should be `4`, `3`, `2`, `1` in descending order.

The degeneracies are the reason why for most states you get superpositions that don't look like the rotationally symmetrized Gauss-Laguerre functions of Gauss-Hermite functions - but they are valid solutions nonetheless (to within the accuracy of the discretization):

```
ListDensityPlot[Partition[v[[4]],2nX+1],PlotRange->All]
```

[image: state 4]

In the construction of `h`, I used a trick to compute the matrix corresponding to the Laplacian: it invokes the `AdjacencyMatrix` of a `GridGraph`. In principle, it may be better to instead use `NDSolve'FiniteDifferenceDerivative` for this. But I think it's a cute fact that this particular `AdjacencyMatrix` also works. I may get back to adding an alternative approach using the `NDSolve` functionality later.

This is a quick-and dirty implementation without bells and whistles, but it shows the main steps. It also shows that the boundary effects at the edge of the grid are not important as long as you only look at states that are low enough in energy so as to not reach that boundary. This is also why time-dependent wave packet solutions in the same potential can be modeled on a finite grid.

**Edit**

The next step is to apply the method to an *anisotropic* harmonic oscillator, with potential energy $V(x,y) = 1/2 (x^2 + y^2 + x y)$, as was asked for in the comments:

```
nX = 20;
a = .2;

Clear[v];
v[x_, y_] := 1/2 (x^2 + y^2 + x y)

vGrid = Table[v[a i, a j], {i, -nX, nX}, {j, -nX, nX}];

xyList = Tuples[Range[1, 2 nX + 1], 2];

Timing[h = 
   DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[(vGrid[[##]] & @@@ xyList) + 2/a^2]] - 
    1/(2 a^2) AdjacencyMatrix[GridGraph[{2 nX + 1, 2 nX + 1}]];]

(* ==>{0.009491,Null}*)

v = Eigenvectors[h, -10];

ListDensityPlot[Partition[v[[10]], 2 nX + 1], PlotRange -> All]

(* ==> {0.008648, Null} *)
```

[image: ground state2]

As expected, the ground state now is deformed (elliptical) and oriented along a diagonal.

**Edit 2: an even more basic approach**

To avoid any advanced functions that may not be present in older versions of *Mathematica*, here is a practically identical formulation where the finite-difference approximation is constructed in a more straight-forward (i.e. low-level) way. I'm again using the *anisotropic* oscillator of the last example - everything up to `xyList` is copied verbatim from above.

```
nX = 20;
a = .2;

Clear[v];
v[x_, y_] := 1/2 (x^2 + y^2 + x y)

vGrid = Table[v[a i, a j], {i, -nX, nX}, {j, -nX, nX}];

xyList = Tuples[Range[1, 2 nX + 1], 2];

ClearAll[hash];
Evaluate[hash /@ xyList] = Range[Length[xyList]];
hash[{0, n_}] := hash[{2 nX + 1, n}];
hash[{n_, 0}] := hash[{n, 2 nX + 1}];
hash[{2 nX + 2, n_}] := hash[{1, n}];
hash[{n_, 2 nX + 2}] := hash[{n, 1}];

s1 = 
  SparseArray[
   Flatten[Table[{{hash[{i, j}], hash[{i, j + 1}]} -> 
       1, {hash[{i, j}], hash[{i + 1, j}]} -> 
       1, {hash[{i, j}], hash[{i, j - 1}]} -> 
       1, {hash[{i, j}], hash[{i - 1, j}]} -> 1}, {i, 1, 
      2 nX + 1}, {j, 1, 2 nX + 1}]]];

h1 = 
  DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[(vGrid[[##]] & @@@ xyList) + 2/a^2]] - 
   1/(2 a^2) s1;
```

This is the equivalent to `h` in the previous examples. It is the Hamiltonian matrix that will now be diagonalized to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

```
e1 = Eigenvalues[h1, -10]

(*
==> {4.09354, 3.77227, 3.58063, 3.39729, 3.07122, 2.88156, \
2.36968, 2.1824, 1.66728, 0.963587}
*)

v1 = Eigenvectors[h1, -10];

ListDensityPlot[Partition[v1[[4]], 2 nX + 1], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: hermite]

Here I chose to plot an excited state instead of the ground state because it shows nicely that after breaking the rotational symmetry we don't have degeneracies anymore and therefore get eigenfunctions that look like the expected Gauss-Hermit functions in both orthogonal directions (along the diagonals), as one would also obtain by first finding the normal modes exactly. This finite difference algorithm of course doesn't know or care about the existence of rotational symmetry or separability, so it will also work with binding potentials that are not harmonic oscillators.

**Regarding three dimensions**

The generalization to higher dimensions is in principle quite straightforward, but you'll have to consult some text on finite-difference methods to construct the second-derivate stencil properly. In those cases, the availability of built-in methods becomes really useful. There is a lot more to read about this in [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html) (search for `FiniteDifferenceDerivative`, it will in fact tell you how to construct a 2D Laplacian).

**Edit to generalize my first approach to 3D**

To generalize my earlier `AdjacencyMatrix` trick to three dimensions, you would need to calculate the Hamiltonian as follows:

```
h = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[(vGrid[[##]] & @@@ xyList) + 3/a^2]] - 
    1/(2 a^2) AdjacencyMatrix[GridGraph[{2 nX + 1, 2 nX + 1, 2 nX + 1}]]
```

Note the factor `3` instead of `2` in the additive constant on the diagonal. The constant on the diagonal is `1/a^2` times the number of dimensions of the grid.

The difference between using `AdjacencyMatrix` and the last approach is in the boundary conditions. The `AdjacencyMatrix` method does not implement periodic boundary conditions, whereas the last approach does. However, these boundary conditions are irrelevant in the present calculation because the bound states are assumed to not feel the boundary anyway.

I like the `AdjacencyMatrix` approach mainly because it is a more descriptive formulation, saying in code what the topology of the laplacian matrix really looks like.

**Edit regarding grid spacing**

To change the grid spacing without changing the physics, you have to keep the product `a*nX` large enough to ensure that the eigenstates you're interested in are not affected by the grid boundary. The value `a*nX` is the largest `x` or `y` coordinate that will be sampled, and your potential at those coordinates should be high enough to exclude the wave function of any relevant eigenstate from the boundary.

One could also combine this algorithm with my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44153/245) to insure that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are sorted in the correct way.

**Edit regarding differentiation order**

For completeness, and in response to the comments, I'm also listing another approach based on the built-in function `NDSolve'FiniteDifferenceDerivative`, which allows us to specify the differentiation order. This overcomes the limitation of the previous methods which use the lowest-order finite-difference approximation to the second derivative. *Mathematica* is able to generate finite-difference derivative matrices for higher order, by specifying the option `"DifferenceOrder"` as shown below. The value `4` is actually the default.

```
nX = 20;
a = .2;

Clear[v];
v[x_, y_] := 1/2 (x^2 + y^2 + x y)

vGrid = Table[v[a i, a j], {i, -nX, nX}, {j, -nX, nX}];
xRange = Range[1, 2 nX + 1];
xyList = Tuples[xRange, 2];

h2 = DiagonalMatrix[
    SparseArray[(vGrid[[##]] & @@@ xyList)]] - 
    1/(2 a^2) Sum[
     NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[i, {xRange, xRange}, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 4]["DifferentiationMatrix"], 
    {i, {{2, 0}, {0, 2}}}];

{en2, ψ2} = Eigensystem[h2, -10];

ListDensityPlot[Partition[ψ2[[5]], 2 nX + 1], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: psi[5]]

Using higher differentiation order is then simply a matter of changing the value `4` to something else, and making sure that the grid is large enough to give sensible results for that order.

This is the two-dimensional generalization of what I did in a closely related answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51308/245).

Comment: Fantastic. But it is very concise. I am going through it, but it would be great if you could add some extra explanation to it.

Comment: It seems to me NDSolve will be more straightforward. I am looking enthusiastically for how it works. God bless you!

Comment: Actually, this is pretty much the simplest approach I can think of. By using `NDSolve` functionality, I only meant that the approximation for the second derivatives in the kinetic energy can be improved using some built-in functions. But the remainder, i.e., the construction and diagonalization of `h`, will stay the same. I'll hopefully get to that modification tomorrow.

Comment: I would like to go through a Fourier analysis of its wave packet. Is your approach [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27842/complex-valued-21d-pde-schroedinger-equation-numerical-method-for-ndsolve?lq=1) for finding the evolution of the wave packet, applicable for 2D H. O.? Because there, the potential you have considered is periodic, but here is not.

Comment: @NoOne No, you do have to modify the potential to make it consistent with the periodic boundary conditions. This could be done artificially while still maintaining a parabolic minimum in the center. But I'll have to let you try to figure that out yourself... in the meantime, could you modify your original question to include the ho potential $x^2 + y^2 + x y$? That's the more doable test case, after all.

Comment: It is x^2 + y^2 + xy in the original question.

Comment: When I used your above code (for (1/2)(x^2 + y^2)), it did not return any eigenvalues, and it seems, it is working... . Is this problem caused by the low speed of my laptop? And why does the number that has been returned as "Null" is different from you, what does it mean?

Comment: I am using Mathematica 7.0, I think my problem is due to this fact.

Comment: Yes, "AdjacencyMatrix" is not included in Mathematica 7.0 .

Comment: @NoOne Ah, version 7 doesn't have `AdjacencyMatrix` - I'll add an alternative approach later. I thought what I did was actually more likely to work in all versions, but I guessed wrong...

Comment: Why do the eigenvalues drastically change by changing the length of the grid step, i. e. "a", for example from 0.2 to 0.05 or to 0.1?

Comment: @NoOne With the scaling I used, the issue is that small `a` must be compensated by larger `nX` in order to avoid overlap of the wave function with the grid boundary where the finite-difference method fails. I added that to the end of the answer.

Comment: This deserves more upvotes...

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. You write: 'Finally, we have to construct the kinetic energy, i.e., the Laplacian. This is the only off-diagonal part of the matrix. How far off the diagonal its matrix elements extend depends on the order of the finite-difference approximation by which we replace the second derivatives in the Laplacian. Here I chose the simplest possible approximation.' Could you also explain how to construct the a more general case? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: @andi I may be able to do that - give me a few hours.

Comment: @ Jens. Great! I really did not get how to achieve this myself! Thank you very much!

Comment: @andi I added the info that you were asking for (I think).

Comment: @ Jens: yes, I think this does the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jens: Maybe I could ask you even one more thing; how would I change a particles mass in the code?

Comment: It's relatively simple: if you have chosen a length unit by specifying `a` in the code, you need to bring the kinetic-energy term into the form $-(1/2) d^2/dx^2$. To do this, you have to choose the unit of *energy* appropriately.

Comment: @ Jens  Dear Jens,  I tried to substitute off-hand here a potential of a different kind: `v[x_, y_] := -(1/Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2) + 0.0001])` for which the solution is known, but this `ListPlot3D[Partition[v[[10]], 2 nX + 1], PlotRange -> All]` shows something looking quite unexpectedly. Could you please comment, if the above approach will also work with potentials of different (from harmonic) types?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch It definitely also works for other well-behaved potential shapes - but the Coulomb potential, even with the small cutoff you added, is not well-behaved. Whenever you have near-singularities, the finite-difference method won't work unless you scale out the singularity somehow (by using known analytic behavior near the singularity). Of course for the Coulomb case, you should instead use rotational symmetry first.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch To numerically get the known solutions for the problem you mentioned, see [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113906/245).

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch The method in this answer actually works fine for the Coulomb potential, too - *provided* you discard solutions with angular momentum $m=0$. You can recognize the nonzero-$m$ solutions by the fact that they are going to appear in approximate doublets (almost equal eigenvalues). Those solutions can be made to agree with the exact solutions because they have vanishing measure at the singularity. Of course, you also need ever larger spatial domains when approaching the ionization threshold.

Comment: @Jens  Thank you for this answer. Its a great help. My equations are not really physical Schrödinger ones. They come from bifurcation theory and only look like Schrödinger. But they are 2D, no angular momentum and no rotational symmetry. Anyway, before I asked you, I tried to use the `NDEigensystem` approach by placing the zero Dirichlet condition at a finite, large distance from the origin. The result has been poor. My question now is, if the good result that you show in your answer cited above is due to the mapping `r=tan(ksi)` you used, or it is the `Method` you used, that matters?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I'd say it's both. The rescaling helps avoid setting an artificial cutoff distance, but the finite element method adds the nice ability to have an adaptive mesh (which the method in this answer doesn't have). The finite-difference method with a rigid grid (i.e. what I do here) has the advantage of being pretty fast, though.