# Finding the eigenfunctions of one and two dimensional Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: differential-equations

(Edited)
For finding the ground state wave function of:

$ H\psi(x) = (-1/2)d^2\psi(x)/dx^2 + (1/2)x^2\psi(x) = E \psi(x)$

I have written:

```
mOneDSchEq[n_] :=
Table[Switch[i - j, -1, p[x[i]], 
0, (10/(n + 1))^2 q[x[i]] - 2 p[x[i]], 1, p[x[i]], _, 0], {i, 
n}, {j, n}];

q[x_] := -x^2; p[x_] := 1;
Xarray[n_] := Do[x[i] = -5 + i 10/(n + 1), {i, 0, n + 1}];

EigVec[n_] := Eigenvectors[mOneDSchEq[n]];
lisEigVec = EigVec[35];
OneEigVec[j_] := Part[Reverse[lisEigVec], j];
y[i_] := Part[OneEigVec[1], i];
listOfPoints = 
Join[{{x[0], 0}}, Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 1, 35}], {{x[36], 0}}];
ListPlot[listOfPoints, PlotJoined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotLabel -> "Ground State Wave Function of Harmonic Oscillator", 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

Which I have obtained the Gaussian, correctly.

The question that came to my mind is that:

Is it possible by knowing the ground stat eigenvalue, i.e. 1/2, solving the Schrödinger equation numerically, and obtain the ground state wave function? in other words, to solve:

$ H\psi(x) = (-1/2)d^2\psi(x)/dx^2 + (1/2)x^2\psi(x) = (1/2) \psi(x)$

or

$ H\psi(x) = (-1/2)d^2\psi(x)/dx^2 + (1/2)x^2\psi(x) = (3/2) \psi(x)$

So, I wrote:

```
s = NDSolve[{-(1/2) \[Psi]''[x] + (1/2) x^2(\[Psi][x]) == (1/2) \[Psi][
  x], \[Psi][-5] == 0, \[Psi][5] == 0}, \[Psi], {x, -5, 5}]

Plot[Evaluate[\[Psi][x] /. s], {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

BUT, I got nothing. What is the problem?

The other question is that, I was traveling through the website and found an elegant approach to two dimensional Harmonic Oscillator [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50763/schroedinger-eigenvalue-problem-in-two-dimensions-harmonic-oscillator).

My question is, if again we want to solve the Schrödinger equation numercally and obtain wave functions, now two dimensional, by knowing the eigenvalues, what should we do? For example:

$ H\psi(x,y) = (-1/2)(d^2/x^2 + d^2/dy^2)\psi(x,y) + (1/2)(x^2 + y^2)\psi(x,y) = (1) \psi(x,y) $

and

$ H\psi(x,y) = (-1/2)(d^2/x^2 + d^2/dy^2)\psi(x,y) + (1/2)(x^2 + y^2+ x y)\psi(x,y) = (0.96) \psi(x,y) $

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: In Jens' answer, isn't the `1/(2 a^2)` bit there to take into account the factor of 1/2 in front of the laplacian? Also, the `Partition` is there because he is representing 2d space in a 1d vector (basically, he discretises space, then take the 2d matrix and set the rows one after the other to each other so as to form a 1d vector; the `Partition` undoes this). I'll write an answer tomorrow if I remember, have time and nobody else does!

Comment: Actually I removed "2" in the denominator of 1/(2 a^2), but the answer seemed to me non-sense! and also, why did not plot the two dimensional wave function directly, and he used ListDensityPlot?

Comment: Hmm sorry, I didn't understand; can you rephrase?

Comment: I removed 2 in the denominator and also 1/2 in the potentials, so I expect to obtain two times of energy, i.e. 2E; but It was not.

Comment: to Jens: I tried to comment there, but I was not allowed!

Comment: You need a minimum reputation to comment, here's an upvote to get you there.

Comment: Also you need to notify @Jens like I just did for him to get a message

Comment: @acl - indeed, it's easy to overlook things like "Jens" hidden in a new question...

Comment: How can I notify somebody?

Comment: @Jens I think the confusion is in understanding how you are making the 2d space into a 1d vector, and how you unwind this with the `Partition`

Comment: with a @, like @Jens (hi Jens!)

Comment: @Jens, I appreciate If you could come to my posted question.

Comment: FYI, from the documentation, which should explain what they mean: [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) [`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListDensityPlot.html)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I read there, but I was confused why he didn't plot the usual two dimensional graph of the wave function?

Comment: I suppose it was his choice.  Use `ListPlot3D` instead, if you wish.

Comment: Regarding the added term on the diagonal that you removed in my other answer: changing the diagonal shifts all the eigenvalues. In particular, omitting that positive offset makes some eigenvalues negative.  But *Mathematica* always sorts the eigenvalues in descending order of **absolute** value. This will place the desired ground state somewhere in a (hard to find) non-extremal location in the list of eigenvectors. That's why you think you see nonsense. It's just a wrong eigenstate, not the ground state.

Comment: Interesting. Such a tricky!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To give another answer for the **one-dimensional harmonic oscillator**, let's use a different approach based on the `NDSolve` functionality I alluded to in the [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50765/245). **Edit:** I also update the linked answer to include the analogue of this approach in two dimensions.

```
n = 2000;
a = .02;
grid = N[a Range[-n, n]];
derivative2 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, grid]["DifferentiationMatrix"]
```

> `SparseArray[<20009>,{4001,4001}]`

```
potential = Map[(1/2 #^2) &, grid];

hamiltonian = -derivative2/2 + 
   DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[potential]];

eigenvalues = Chop[Eigenvalues[hamiltonian, -10]]
```

> `{9.5, 8.5, 7.5, 6.5, 5.5, 4.5, 3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5}`

```
v = Chop[Eigenvectors[hamiltonian, -10]];

ListLinePlot[{Abs[v[[-1]]]^2, Abs[v[[-2]]]^2, 
  Abs[v[[-3]]]^2}, DataRange -> grid[[{1, -1}]], 
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, All}]
```

[image: plot of three functions]

Here I used a grid spacing of `a = 0.02` and get numerically very exact solutions for the lowest states of the harmonic oscillator.

The matrix representing the second derivatives (`derivative2`) in the Laplacian is generated using `FiniteDifferenceDerivative`.

**To address some of the other issues in the question:**

The initial code in the question didn't produce a result for me. However, since you state you got the desired result, I assume that there is some typo in the question. Definitely, one can improve the first code block by wrapping the generated Hamiltonian matrix in `N` to make it into a machine-precision matrix that can be diagonalized much faster.

However, the main question seems to have been: why does the differential equation

```
s = 
 NDSolve[{-(1/2) ψ''[x] + (1/2) x^2 (ψ[x]) == (1/2) ψ[
      x], ψ[-5] == 0, ψ[5] == 0}, ψ[x], {x, -5, 5}];
Clear[x];
ψSol[x_] = ψ[x] /. s[[1, 1]];

Plot[Evaluate[ψSol[x]], {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

yield an apparently empty plot? The answer is that the boundary conditions are incorrect if you're looking for a non-trivial solution. The solver actually finds the only possible answer, $\psi(x)\equiv 0$ for all $x$. But this is because you forced the wave function to be zero at two points whereas the ground state by definition has no nodes!

So you should solve the following equation instead:

```
s = 
 NDSolve[{-(1/2) ψ''[x] + (1/2) x^2 (ψ[x]) == (1/2) ψ[
      x], ψ[0] == 1, ψ'[0] == 0}, ψ[x], {x, -5, 5}];
Clear[x];
ψSol[x_] = ψ[x] /. s[[1, 1]];

Plot[Evaluate[ψSol[x]], {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: gaussian]

This yields the expected Gaussian. I chose boundary conditions for the function to be `1` and its derivative to be `0` at the origin.

Comment: It is much more complicated than I expected. But, as I asked in the question, if, for example the eigenvalue is given 1/2, why does not my simple approach in the question work?

Comment: @JensI assumed -5 and 5 physical infinity, where the wave function vanishes.

Comment: But then you can't blame *Mathematica* for giving you the exact solution satisfying your approximate assumption.

Comment: And in your two dimensional isotropic case, if E = 1 is given for example, is your plot there, reproducible by solving the differential equation for E = 1?

Comment: No, that won't work. The real problem is that this is an elliptical boundary-value problem, for which `NDSolve` is not always able to give the solutions you want. That's why the approach based on matrix diagonalization is still necessary. In one dimension, the boundary-value problem isn't too hard because there is only one independent variable. But when there are more than 2 variables, you have a partial differential equation for which `NDSolve` is usually not able to find a solution.

Comment: So what should we do?! for example in the potential (1/2)(x^2 + y^2), we simply know that the eingenvalues are 1, 2, ... . But now, for example, we want to know the eigenfunction corresponding to E = 2.

Comment: obviously by using Mathematica, not decoupling oscillators.

Comment: That's what the earlier answer addresses. I don't think I can say anything beyond that.

Comment: For this potential 1/2 (x^2 + y^2 + x y), which you have discussed here [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50763/schroedinger-eigenvalue-problem-in-two-dimensions-harmonic-oscillator?lq=1], if we use ListPlot3D instead of ListDensityPlot, i. e. 'ListPlot3D[Partition[v[[10]], 2 nX + 1], 
 PlotRange -> All], why do x and y in the result shape posses only positive values? What don't appear negative values of x and y in the plot?

Comment: @SomeBody Because it's the ground state.

Comment: Could you explain it more? In the potential 1/2 x^2, the ground state, Gaussian, is an even function and x runs, for example from -4 to 4 and the vanishes. I mean that in 1/2 (x^2 + y^2 + x y), x and y also in principle could run from negative to positive values, but in ListPlot3D we cannot see such a thing.

Comment: In other words, in ListPlot3D[Partition[v[[10]], 2 nX + 1], PlotRange -> All] how can I change this code, to see clearly in the plot that x and y posses also negative values.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're asking. Perhaps you merely want to add the option `DataRange -> {{-4,4},{-4,4}}` as I did in this answer for the 1D case. You can look at the documentation for `ListPlot3D` for details on this option. This must be what you're after...

Comment: Yes, my English is so poor, and I am so sorry that I confused you. I need that DataRange! Thank you again.

Comment: I read ListPlot3D documentation, but nowhere indicated to DataRange!

Comment: It's in there. Look carefully under `Options`.