# Probability Function in a 1D Quantum Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: differential-equations, probability-or-statistics

Let me start off by saying that I am a complete newbie to Mathematica, so I don't really know what I'm doing.

For my assignment I have to find the numerical probability of a particle in a harmonic oscillator potential in between quantum numbers $n=0$ and $n=5$. For simplicity's sake, I am only trying to find the probability where $n=0$.

The wave function of n=0 in a harmonic oscillator is:

$\Psi(x)$ = $N_0H_0 e^{(-x^2/2)}$

So the probability of finding a particle with the given wave function is:

$\int \Psi^2(x) dx$

The classically bound region is defined as $y= \frac 12{kx^2}$

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
norm[n_] := (1/(Sqrt[π] 2^n n!))^(1/2)

u[x_, n_] := 1/Sqrt[a] norm[n] HermiteH[n, x/a] exp^[-(a*x^2/2)]

b[x_]  := 0.5 kx^2

φ1[x_, n_] :=  1/Sqrt[2 π] NIntegrate[u[x, n]^2, {x, -1, 1}, {n, 0, 5}]
```

However, this does not result in any output. I am wondering how you could format this to result in a valid output, and how to get the numerical probability within the bounds of $y= \frac 12{kx^2}$ and $E_v = \hbar \omega (v + 1)$.

Comment: This problem just happens to have been solved in the *Neat examples* under `Filling`.  Type `?Filling`, click on the `>>` and scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks! How would I be able to find the integral of the area underneath the squared functions in between the parabola?

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your code. Replace `exp` by `Exp`, separate `k` and `x^2`, define `a`. The definition `φ1[x_, n_] :=` doesn't make sense. Use `φ1[ n_] :=` instead. Then evaluate `φ1[1] `. The function is also missing a calculation of the classical turning points as integration limits. Related: [Find eigen energies of time-independent Schrödinger equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51300/245).

Comment: Ok if I have my function as:

`f[n_, x_] := Abs[((1/Pi)^(1/4) HermiteH[n, x])/(E^(x^2/2) Sqrt[2^n n!])]^2
   
xtp := Sqrt[(2*n + 1)/a]
    
a := 1
    
NIntegrate[f[0, x], {x, -t, t}]`  <\br>

Comment: but I don't know how to get >xtp to output a value

Comment: I don't know if your above function definition will (eventually) get you want you want but there are three things:  (1) `NIntegrate` does not do symbolic integration, i.e., you need to assign values to `t`, (2) You can use `Integrate`, and (3) you should put such modifications in the question rather than the comments.  That's what the `edit` button is for.

Comment: You should read about the difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed`. You won't get output from `SetDelayed` (`:=`), but from `=`. Basically, `:=` defines functions that will be evaluated when you invoke their name again later (usually with arguments).

Answer (score 2):

If you use `NIntegrate`, you need to assign all the values. Correcting your syntax:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
norm[n_] := (1/(Sqrt[Pi] 2^n n!))^(1/2)

u[x_, n_] := 1/Sqrt[a] norm[n] HermiteH[n, x/a] Exp[-(a*x^2/2)]
```

Assign a value to `a`, which I don't see in your code:

```
a = 1
```

You are integrating over `x`, but you want a table for `n`, so tell that to MMa.

```
Table[1/Sqrt[2 Pi] NIntegrate[u[x, n]^2, {x, -1, 1}], {n, 0, 5}]
(*{0.336189, 0.170585, 0.0877831, 0.115384, 0.0808829, 0.0739828}*)
```

These values give you the probabilities for finding the particle for x from -1 to 1, but that is not the range of x values you want if you want the limits of the parabolic potential.  To find those values, you need to set `E == V`, the potential and energy, and solve for x from

```
(1/2)*k*x^2 == (n + 1/2)*h*nu
```

which requires assigning all the values for that equation also.
In this case you can also use `Integrate` requiring no prior value assignments.

```
a =.

Table[1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Integrate[u[x, n]^2, {x, -xm, xm}], {n, 0, 5}] // Simplify
```

Most of the values get too long to print here, but for example for n = 0 we get:

```
Erf[Sqrt[a]*xm]/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*a^(3/2))
```

where xm are the x limits found from setting `E = V`