# How to prevent instability blow up in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, stability

I have the following code to solve a PDE:

```
e = 2.5;
xmax = 5;
ymax = 5;
sol[x_, y_] = f[x, y] /. First@NDSolve[{
     -D[f[x, y], x, x] - D[f[x, y], y, y] == e f[x, y],
     Derivative[0, 1][f][x, -ymax] == Cos[\[Pi]/(2 xmax) x],
     f[x, -ymax] == 0,
     f[-xmax, y] == 0,
     f[xmax, y] == 0
     }, f[x, y], {x, -xmax, xmax}, {y, -ymax, ymax}]
```

I'd expect to get a `Sin[]`-like solution in `y` direction, but what I get instead is this:

```
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, -xmax, xmax}, {y, -ymax, ymax}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "f"},  MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

If I try using something like `MaxStepSize -> 0.25`, then the blow-up is just more frequent in `x` direction, and becomes visible at even smaller `y` values:

[image]

What can I do to prevent this blow-up and make `NDSolve` give the expected solution?

**EDIT**

In fact, the problem above is a minimal example showing the instability. What I'd actually like to solve is the equation with additional `+U[x,y]f[x,y]` on the LHS, where `U[x,y]=-70Exp[-x^2-y^2]`. I.e. the equation would look like

```
-D[f[x, y],x,x]-D[f[x,y],y,y]-70Exp[-x^2-y^2]f[x,y]==e f[x,y]
```

So, the answer I'm looking for should be extensible to this case. The answer by @xzczd solves the problem with minimal example, but unfortunately fails to extend to this one.

Comment: Just a check. Do you mean to have both second derivative terms as negative? If you are trying to solve the wave equation then the first one should be positive. If both are negative then the solutions may blow up. Changing the sign of the first term gives a good solution.

Comment: @Hugh no, the equation is as intended, with both derivatives negative. I do understand that solutions _could_ blow up in some circumstances (e.g. when `e<0`), but in this case the solution `NDSolve` gives blows up with the frequency of the grid, so in the limit of infinite grid density the function won't be differentiable, which doesn't look right.

Comment: As bbgodfrey pointed out, many finite-difference-based methods actually become *less* stable when a finer grid is used, rather than more stable (this tends to surprise people, as intuition suggests using a finer grid will usually make things better, not worse). One solution is to use other methods, like Michael E2's suggestion. There might be other ways, too, but I'm not very knowledgeable here.

Comment: Just a side note, today I came across [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X07007172) and noticed your problem is actually ill-posed. Still, a quick search shows there seems to be several techniques to deal with it, but sadly I can't understand those materials I found…

Answer (score 9):

The [Finite Element Method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html) seems more stable for this type of problem.

```
e = 2.5;
xmax = 5;
ymax = 5;
sol = First@
   NDSolve[{-D[f[x, y], x, x] - D[f[x, y], y, y] + NeumannValue[Cos[\[Pi]/(2 xmax) x], y == -ymax] == e f[x, y], 
     DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 0, y > -ymax]}, 
    f, {x, -xmax, xmax}, {y, -ymax, ymax}, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}];

Plot3D[f[x, y] /. sol, {x, -xmax, xmax}, {y, -ymax, ymax}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "f"}, PlotPoints -> 101]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can use `"MeshOptions"` to control the quality of the solution (as described in the linked tutorial above). Comparing the boundary condition along `y == -ymax`, we see that `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01` helps to meet the condition much better than the default of `0.25`:

```
Plot[{Cos[π/(2 xmax) x], D[f[x, y], y] /. sol /. y -> -ymax} // Evaluate, {x, -xmax, xmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I hope it works in your actual use case! :)

Comment: This is a great answer. Would you know why the default method does not check its convergence and falls back onto this solution? It makes using NDSolve hazardous that no such validation is carried out?

Comment: @MichaelE2 unfortunately it requires Mathematica 10. Still interesting anyway. What would be the way to add `U[x,y]f[x,y]` to the LHS of the equation with this awkward Neumann condition syntax?

Comment: @Ruslan I *think* there might be a way to do FEM in V9....I'm not sure how much work it would take.  See for instance Jens' answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50763/schroedinger-eigenvalue-problem-in-two-dimensions-harmonic-oscillator/50765#50765).

Comment: @chris Thanks.  I don't know how `NDSolve` chooses the method.  It may have to do with the OP's setup.  Someone from WRI might see your comment and be able to respond.

Comment: It seems your formulation of the problem is not the same as the one in the OP. See [wave equation section](http://tinyurl.com/njbxdnd) in the tutorial you linked. The problem in the OP basically only differs by a sign in a derivative (and other minor parts). But there's no `NeumannValue[]` used in the problem setup in that tutorial. And when I try to add a `U[x,y]f[x,y]` term to the LHS of the equation with your formulation, I get completely wrong results, which don't even satisfy initial conditions. (I used `U[x,y]=-70Exp[-x^2-y^2]`). Are you sure your formulation is equivalent to mine?

Comment: @Ruslan How do you account for the boundary condition `Derivative[0, 1][f][x, -ymax] == Cos[\[Pi]/(2 xmax) x]`? That's what the `NeumannValue` is for. For the PDE `-D[f[x, y], x, x] - D[f[x, y], y, y] + 70 Exp[-x^2 - y^2] f[x, y] + NeumannValue[Cos[\[Pi]/(2 xmax) x], y == -ymax] == e f[x, y]`, with the same Dirichlet condition, I get this: [Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLIl7.png)  And it seems to me that all the BCs are satisfied, Neumann and Dirichlet. It's possible I've made a mistake somewhere, but I don't see any inconsistency yet.

Comment: See `In[50]` and `In[51]` in the tutorial section I linked to. The latter is how I'd account for it. Am I wrong? And yes, the initial condition for derivative is not satisfied in your plot. In fact, even for the value of function at $y=-5$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19856/discussion-between-michael-e2-and-ruslan).

Answer (score 7):

Your calculation is unstable, because the Courant limit is violated.  For a square mesh, it is `e > 4 dx^-2`.  Choosing `e=27.5` gives

[image: e=7.5 solution]

Comment: So, what are the workarounds? Maybe some way to use rectangular mesh or some special `Method` of `NDSolve`?

Comment: The equation can be solved analytically, although I have not been able to coax `DSolve` to do it yet..

Comment: Of course it can! But the equations I'm going to solve after fixing the stability problem can't! I just gave a minimal working example.

Comment: What is actual equation you are trying to solve?  Courant limits sometimes are sensitive to details.

Comment: Add `U[x,y]f[x,y]` on the LHS of the equation where `U[x,y]` is some function, and `e>U[x,y]`, then it's the equation I'm trying to solve. Restricting values of `e` beyond this is not a solution, of course.

Comment: I would try a standard finite difference discretization to create a set of algebraic equations in f at the mesh points, then use a Mathematica linear equation solver to obtain the answer.  Probably, `LinearSolve`.

Comment: You also might add a first order time derivative to the equation to turn it into a diffusion  equation, choose a reasonable initial condition, and run the calculation forward in time until it reaches steady state.

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat inspired by [bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey)'s answer, after rereading [the tutorial of "MethodOfLines"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html), I found that a restriction for `"MaxPoints"` together with `"DifferenceOrder" -> 2` solved the problem, no v10-feature is needed!:

```
e = 2.5;
xmax = 5;
ymax = 5;
sol[x_, y_] = 
 f[x, y] /. 
  With[{n = 18}, 
   First@NDSolve[{-D[f[x, y], x, x] - D[f[x, y], y, y] == e f[x, y], 
      Derivative[0, 1][f][x, -ymax] == Cos[π/(2 xmax) x], 
      f[x, -ymax] == 0, f[-xmax, y] == 0, f[xmax, y] == 0}, 
     f[x, y], {x, -xmax, xmax}, {y, -ymax, ymax}, 
     InterpolationOrder -> All, 
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MaxPoints" -> n, "MinPoints" -> n, 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}]]

Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, -xmax, xmax}, {y, -ymax, ymax}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "f"}]
Plot[{Cos[π/(2 xmax) x] - D[sol[x, y], y] /. y -> -ymax} // Evaluate, {x, -xmax, xmax}]
```

[image]

[image]

Notice that `"MinPoints"` option isn't necessary here, but I found it lowers the error, at least at the boundary. And actually if you choose `n = 10`, `"DifferenceOrder -> 2"` can be eliminated, too, though a warning will be generated.

Comment: Great! But I can't seem to extend this to the equation with `+U[x,y]f[x,y]` on the LHS, where `U[x,y]=-70Exp[-x^2-y^2]`. I try to increase `n`, increase difference order, but still the blow up appears at about `y==0` or earlier.

Comment: @Ruslan If this method would have any chance to work, it should be _decreasing_ rather than _increasing_ `n` or `"DifferenceOrder"`, sadly it seems that _decreasing_ doesn't work either 囧.