# Resolving singularity in convection-diffusion equation using pdetoode

Tags: differential-equations, physics, finite-difference-method, fluid-dynamics

Building on the system of equations in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270457/fourth-order-nonlinear-pde-depicting-dynamics-of-liquid-lenses), I attempted to solve an additional convection-diffusion equation describing the concentration of solute in the lens, which affects its spreading.

[image]

However, I noticed that the LHS is multiplied by `h2-h1`. As `h2-h1` could become very small or even negative, it results in the concentration field destabilising and producing sharp peaks (ie a sudden gain of solute).

[image]

I have attempted to resolve the issue using `unitStepExpand@If[(h2 - h1) < hinf, hinf, (h2 - h1)]` as in this post ([Error in Attempting Moving Boundary Fluid System](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269770/error-in-attempting-moving-boundary-fluid-system/269796#269796)). However,  NDSolveValue fails to initialise after a long time and the kernel crashes.

The code can be found below, and the definition of [pdetoode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/87074) can be found here. I am currently using a graded mesh that is finer in the region with the lens. I have also tried a uniform grid, as can be created below:

```
domain = {-20, 20}; 
points = 120; 
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
```

This initialises but uses extremely small timesteps of `10^-7` s.

Thus, how could I ensure that h2-h1 remains positive and non-zero? Thank you!

```
With[{h1 = h1[r, t], h2 = h2[r, t], c = c[r, t]},
 p1[c_] := -(\[Gamma]ow[c]/r)*D[r*D[h1, r], r] - \[Gamma]w[c]/r*
    D[r*D[h2, r], r];
 p2[c_] := -\[Gamma]w[c]/r*D[r*D[h2, r], r] - \[CapitalPi]dep2[
    h2 - h1, c];]

unitStepExpand = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@# &;
With[{h1 = h1[r, t], h2 = h2[r, t], c = c[r, t], P1 = P1[r, t], 
  P2 = P2[r, t], q1 = q1[r, t], q2 = q2[r, t]},
 Acoeff = 
  Simplify[-h1*D[P1, r] - (h2 - h1)*D[P2, r] + D[\[Gamma]w[c], r] + 
    D[\[Gamma]ow[c], r]];
 Ccoeff = D[\[Gamma]w[c], r] - h2*D[P2, r];
 Dcoeff = 
  Simplify[Mrat*(-(1/2)*h1^2*D[P1, r] - h1*(h2 - h1)*D[P2, r] + 
       h1*(D[\[Gamma]w[c], r] + D[\[Gamma]ow[c], r])) - 
    1/2*h1^2*D[P2, r] - h1*D[\[Gamma]w[c], r] + h1*h2*D[P2, r]];
 eqp1 = P1 == p1[c];
 eqp2 = P2 == p2[c];
 eqq1 = q1 == Simplify[1/\[Mu]o*(1/6*h1^3*D[P1, r] + 1/2*h1^2*Acoeff)];
 eqq2 = q2 == 
   Simplify[
    1/\[Mu]w*(1/6*D[P2, r]*(h2^3 - h1^3) + Ccoeff/2*(h2^2 - h1^2) + 
       Dcoeff*(h2 - h1))];
 eqh1 = D[h1, t] == -1/r*D[r*q1, r];
 eqh2 = D[h2, t] == -1/r*D[r*q1, r] - 1/r*D[r*q2, r] - J[c];
 eqc =(*(h2-h1)*)
  unitStepExpand@If[(h2 - h1) < hinf, hinf, (h2 - h1)]*
    D[c, t] == (diff/r*D[r*(h2 - h1)*D[c, r], r] - q2/r*D[r*c, r] - 
     J[c]*c);
 ic = {h1 == Hbath, h2 == hinit, c == cinit} /. t -> 0;
 ]

hinf = 0.00001; 
ccrit = 0.32152;(*from simulation data used here, where S=0*)

\[CapitalPi]dep2[h_, c_] := (2*Sfunc[c])/
  hinf*(hinf/h)^3*(1 - Sfunc[0]/Sfunc[c]*(hinf/h)^3);

(*interfacial tensions*)
\[Gamma]ow[c_] := 0.0312 - 0.0177*c + 7.97*10^-3*c^2;
\[Gamma]o = 0.0309;
\[Gamma]w[c_] := 4.94*10^-3 - 8*10^-4*c - 1.12*10^-3*c^2;
Sfunc[c_] := \[Gamma]o - \[Gamma]ow[c] - \[Gamma]w[c];
Plot[Sfunc[c], {c, 0, 1}]

\[Mu]o = 4.88*10^-5;(*https://downloads.hindawi.com/archive/2014/\
234583.pdf*)
\[Mu]w = 2.75*10^-6;(*https://www.rheosense.com/applications/\
viscosity/two-component-mixtures*)
Mrat = \[Mu]w/\[Mu]o;

diff = 0.4*10^-3;(*diffusion coefficient*)
J[c_] := 7.3*10^-4*c;(*evap rate*)

(*initial conditions*)
hinit = hinf + Hbath + 0.25 E^(-r^2);
cinit = 0.45*0.5 (1 + Tanh[1.5*(1.2 - Abs[r])]);

(*Generate graded grid*)

Hbath = 3;
ldrop = 10; ndrop = 90;(*number of grid points in the region*)
loil = 10; noil = 40;
dropgrid = Subdivide[ldrop, ndrop];(*non-graded mesh for drop*)
size = dropgrid[[2]]
oilgridmid = Table[size + (1/8*i)^2, {i, 0, loil, loil/noil}];
oilgrid = 
 Table[ldrop + size*i, {i, 0, Length[oilgridmid] - 1}] + oilgridmid
combined = Union[dropgrid, oilgrid];
reflected = DeleteCases[Union[combined, -combined], 0];
toplot = Transpose[{reflected, Table[1, {i, 1, Length[reflected]}]}];
ListPlot[toplot(**), PlotStyle -> PointSize[Small]]

(*Discretisation and Solving*)

grid = reflected;
difforder = 2;
domain = {Min[grid], Max[grid]}

tfunc = pdetoode[{h1, h2, c, P1, P2, q1, q2}[r, t], t, grid, 
   difforder, True];
odemid = Map[tfunc, {eqp1, eqp2, eqq1, eqq2}, {2}];
ode = Block[{P1, P2, q1, q2}, Set @@@ odemid;
   tfunc@{eqh1, eqh2, eqc}];
odeic = tfunc@ic;
var = Outer[#[#2] &, {h1, h2, c}, grid];

timer = 0.11;
time = 0;

Monitor[sol = 
   NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic}, var, {t, 0, timer}, 
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> (time = t)], time];

{h1sol, h2sol, csol} = rebuild[#, grid, 2] & /@ sol;
Manipulate[
 Plot[{h1sol[r, t], h2sol[r, t], csol[r, t]}, {r, ##}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 3.3}}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"] & @@ domain, {t, 0, timer}]
```

**Edits**

Using a much finer graded grid, with 500 points from `{0,10}` and 50 points from `{10,30}`, we observe that the droplet concentration forms a clear step function before eventually exploding. **This verifies that the instability is likely caused by the sharp discontinuity in the concentration field.**

Since the numerical instability is caused by discontinuities in the solution field itself, similar to the [Burger's equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/267890/1871), are there any potential strategies implementable for we to continue using the finite difference scheme? Alternatively, would discretising our problem in a separate domain i.e. finite element scheme allow us to maintain a stable solution despite the discontinuity in the solution field?

[image]

Comment: I doubt if you're in the right direction. 1. According to my (limited) experience, non-uniform grid for FDM can easily lead to instability, that's the reason I myself don't often use it. 2. If you use the `eqc` without `unitStepExpand` and choose a coarse grid e.g. `domain = {-20, 20}; points = 24; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];`, the problem is solved, but problem that can only be solved with coarse grid is sometimes a sign of ill-posed problem. (Example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69918/1871 ) Are you sure the problem itself is correct? Can you add a reference?

Comment: While there isn't an exactly identical model in literature, the research conducted by this paper https://sci-hub.wf/10.1021/la9019469 is quite close. The main difference is that while their spreading is surfactant driven and on solid surfaces, while our spreading is concentration driven and on another fluid. They have managed to solve the diffusion convection equation in the same form, though granted the convection of their fluid is much slower.

Comment: Another paper which is quite similar to ours is this one http://users.auth.gr/gkarapetsas/Publications/Karapetsas%20et%20al.%20-%202011%20-%20Surfactant-driven%20dynamics%20of%20liquid%20lenses.pdf, where they spread a surfactant on a liquid surface. Similarly the original authors managed to solve the diffusion convection equation in the same form, although they had to use finite element as their discretisation scheme instead.

Comment: Btw if our problem is really ill-posed, is there any other ways we could potentially solve it, for instance by discretisation via finite element?

Comment: [FEM is not magic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270978/1871). For problem defined in regular domain, I don't think FEM will show any advantage (as far as the methods have been properly implemented). For any FEM implementation, when element with regular shape is chosen, one can always find an equivlant FDM implementation, I believe.

Comment: I see... If theres any reason for the "ill posed" nature of the problem, however, I think the biggest possibility is that the concentration field at the edges approaches a step function since the disjoined pressure limits the convection, causing the given numerical instability. I'm thinking that a finite element method may help since it allows the problem to be solved in a weak form. Does this seem plausible?

Comment: Also do you have any suggestions why adding unitstepexpand increase the memory consumption of NDSolve so significantly, considering that you have managed to use it without problems the previous occasion... Thank you so much!

Comment: If things like shock wave are supposed to involve in, it'll be really troublesome, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/267890/1871 "`NDSolveValue` fails to initialise after a long time and the kernel crashes." Which version are you in? Just tested the code in _v13.2_ (I didn't tested `eqc` with `unitStepExpand` so far because it seems so slow), with `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"`, `NDSolve` spits out `icfail` warning and give up in 200 s, but doesn't crash; with `"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"`, `NDSolve` manages to solve the problem in 120 s, but the peak remains.

Comment: We have tried our code with Mathematica 12.3, yup the non `unitstepexpand` code works just fine on our side as well, it's just the one with `unitstepexpand` that's extremely slow.

Comment: I mean, the one with `unitStepExpand` is solved in 120 seconds in _v13.2_ when `"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"` is set, but the peak remains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141450/discussion-between-flp-and-xzczd).