# Nonlinear boundary value problem of ODE involving principal value of integral

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear, integral-equations

I have asked a question on a [nonlinear eigenvalue problem (EVP)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198796/solve-a-nonlinear-eigenvalue-problem?noredirect=1#comment514857_198796). And I have worked on these for a week but I cannot solve it. I think I should first try to solve the related ODE boundary value problem on $x\in[-L,L]$:

$$-u^\prime+uu^\prime+u^{\prime\prime}+u^{\prime\prime\prime}+u^{\prime\prime\prime\prime}+\frac{1}{2L}PV\int_{-L}^L u^{\prime\prime\prime}(s)\cot\left(\frac{\pi(x-s)}{2L}\right)\mathrm{d}s=0,$$

where derivatives are denoted by primes, PV represents the principal value of the integral due to the singularity at $x=s$. It should be solved with periodic boundary condition(s): $u(\pm L)=0$ (and $du/dx\vert_{x=\pm L}=0$ if necessary) or $u[-L]=u[L]$. Here, the highest derivative is 4th-order, I think four BCs are needed but not very sure which BCs should be used.

This code does not work. I believe the reason is due to the `NIntegrate`.
Can anyone give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance!

```
L = 20;
sys = {-u'[x] + u[x]*u'[x] + u''[x] + u'''[x] + u''''[x] + 
 1/(2*L)*NIntegrate[u'''[s]*Cot[(π*(x - s))/(2*L)], {s, -L, x, L}, 
   Method -> "PrincipalValue"] == 0,
u[-L] == 0, u[L] == 0, u'[-L] == 0, u'[L] == 0};

sol = First[u /. NDSolve[sys, u, {x, -L, L}]]
```

It gives several warnings like this:

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand `` NDSolve`u$1$2$3$2792 Cot[1/40 π (-20.-s)] `` has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries `{{-20.,20}}`. >>

**Update: try the method provided for [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189698/solution-or-artifact) by @xzczd**

```
L = 20;
fakefunc[x_?NumericQ] = 0;
sys = {u[x]*u'[x] + u''[x] + u''''[x] + 1/(2*L)*fakefunc[x] + u'''[x] == u'[x], u[-L] == 0, u[L] == 0, u'[-L] == 0, u'[L] == 0};

{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[sys, u, {x, -L, L}];

state["NumericalFunction"]["FunctionExpression"]
```

> ```
>  Function[{x, u, NDSolve`u$2$1, NDSolve`u$2$1$2, 
>   NDSolve`u$2$1$2$3}, {NDSolve`u$2$1, NDSolve`u$2$1$2, 
>   NDSolve`u$2$1$2$3, NDSolve`u$2$1 - u NDSolve`u$2$1 - NDSolve`u$2$1$2 - 
>    NDSolve`u$2$1$2$3 - fakefunc[x]/40}]
> ```

```
Clear@int; 
int[y_List, x_] := With[{func = ListInterpolation[D[y, {x, 3}], {{-L, L}}]}, 
NIntegrate[func@s*Cot[π*(x - s)/(2*L)], {s, -L, x, L}, 
Method -> {"PrincipalValue", SymbolicProcessing -> 0}]];

rule = HoldPattern@MapThread[Function[x, fakefunc[x]], {x}, 1] :> (int[u, #] & /@ x)

newstate = state /. rule;
NDSolve`Iterate[newstate]
soltest = u /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions@newstate
```

which do not give any warning. But the plot gives null

```
Plot[Evaluate[soltest[x]], {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> All]
```

**Update(May 26, 2019): a probably failed case**

In the following, @xzczd's answer is tested with another analytic solution $u(x)=sech(x)$, which has the same b.c.s as the original question.

```
L = 30; domain = {-L, L};
points = 61; (*could be reduced to 41*)
difforder = 4; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
(* find pdetoae in the link above. *)

ptoafunc = pdetoae[u[x], grid, difforder];
Clear@nint
nint[u_List, x_List] := nint[u, #] & /@ x;
nint[u : {__?NumericQ}, x_] := With[{func = ListInterpolation[u, {domain}]}, 
NIntegrate[func[s]*Cot[(\[Pi] (x - s))/(2 L)], {s, -L, x, L}, 
Method -> {PrincipalValue, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]]

rhslst = Table[-u'[x] + u[x]*u'[x] + u''[x] + u'''[x] + u''''[x] + 
  1/(2*L)*NIntegrate[u'''[s]*Cot[(\[Pi]*(x - s))/(2*L)], {s, -L, x, L}, 
    Method -> {PrincipalValue, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 8] /. u -> Function[x, Sech[x]] // Evaluate, {x, grid}];
rhsfunc = ListInterpolation[rhslst, grid];

{neweq, newbc} = {-u'[x] + u[x] u'[x] + u''[x] + u'''[x] + u''''[x] + 
1/(2 L) nint[u'''[x], x] == rhsfunc@x, 
With[{lhs = {u[-L] == 0, u[L] == 0, u'[-L] == 0, u'[L] == 0}[[All, 1]]},
lhs == (lhs /. u -> Function[x, Sech[x]]) // Thread]};

del = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;
ae = ptoafunc@neweq // del;
aebc = ptoafunc@newbc;
guess[x_] = 0;
solrule = FindRoot[{ae, aebc}, 
Table[{u@x, guess@x}, {x, grid}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2881.481811, Null} *)

solfunc = ListInterpolation[solrule[[All, -1]], grid];
Plot[solfunc@x, {x, -L, L}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Which is totally different the desired solution:

```
Plot[Sech[x], {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Currently `NDSolve` isn't able to handle `NIntegrate` whose integrand involves the unknown function, AFAIK. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189698/1871

Comment: Notice the method in the previous link won't fully apply to your problem, because the integration exists in the _spatial_ dimension of a PDE system in that question, while yours is a BVP of ODE i.e. the integration exists in _time_ dimension. As long as `Shooting` method is used, tackling ``NDSolve`ProcessEquations`` won't help. (Now in _v12_ `FiniteElement` can handle nonlinear BVP, too, so `FiniteElement` might help. But I haven't looked into this new feature yet. ) We probably need to build our own solver, which won't be that easy, I'm afraid. (Nonlinear BVP is already troublesome. )

Comment: @xzczd oh, formidable nonlinear BVP. Previously, i just think of the difficulty of nonlinear PDE definitely larger than nonlinear BVP. If it becomes a PDE somehow, could it be handled by `NDSolve`` ProcessEquations`? Anyway, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes, if the $x$ becomes the spatial dimension of a PDE, the method in the link above will be fully applicable. (Whether it'll work well or not is another story, though. My limited personal experience is, if the nonlinear BVP of ODE is hard, the corresponding PDE won't be easy to solve, either. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, currently `NDSolve` isn't able to handle `NIntegrate` whose integrand involves the unknown function, AFAIK. The most realistic choice in my view is to leave `NDSolve` alone and build our own solver. The following is my solution. Though it's rather slow, it does work.

It's easy to notice the original BVP owns a trivial solution

$$u=0$$

It might owns non-trivial solution, but to make this answer more interesting and the result easier to check, I'll slightly modify the original equation and b.c.s to

$$-u'+uu'+u''+u'''+u''''+\frac{1}{2L}PV\int_{-L}^L u'''(s)\cot\left(\frac{\pi(x-s)}{2L}\right)\mathrm{d}s=\color{red}{f(x)}$$

$$u(-L)=u(L)=0$$
$$u'(-L)=u'(L)=\color{red}{-\frac{\pi}{L}}$$

where $f(x)$ is a properly chosen function so that the BVP owns the non-trivial solution

$$u=\sin(\frac{\pi x}{L})$$

The idea of this solution is simple: discretize the ODE and b.c.s based on finite difference method (FDM), and solve the resulting nonlinear algebraic system with `FindRoot`. I'll use [pdetoae](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of difference equations.

```
L = 20; domain = {-L, L};
points = 50; difforder = 4; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this answer,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[u[x], grid, difforder];
Clear@nint
nint[u_List, x_List] := nint[u, #] & /@ x;
nint[u : {__?NumericQ}, x_] := 
 With[{func = ListInterpolation[u, {domain}]}, 
  NIntegrate[func[s]*Cot[(π (x - s))/(2 L)], {s, -L, x, L}, 
   Method -> {PrincipalValue, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]]

rhslst = Table[-u'[x] + u[x]*u'[x] + u''[x] + u'''[x] + u''''[x] + 
      1/(2*L)*NIntegrate[u'''[s]*Cot[(π*(x - s))/(2*L)], {s, -L, x, L}, 
        Method -> {PrincipalValue, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 8] /. 
     u -> Function[x, Sin[Pi x/L]] // Evaluate, {x, grid}];
rhsfunc = ListInterpolation[rhslst, grid];

{neweq, newbc} = {-u'[x] + u[x] u'[x] + u''[x] + u'''[x] + u''''[x] + 
     1/(2 L) nint[u'''[x], x] == rhsfunc@x, 
   With[{lhs = {u[-L] == 0, u[L] == 0, u'[-L] == 0, u'[L] == 0}[[All, 1]]}, 
    lhs == (lhs /. u -> Function[x, Sin[Pi x/L]]) // Thread]};
del = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;
ae = ptoafunc@neweq // del;
aebc = ptoafunc@newbc;
guess[x_] = 0;
solrule = FindRoot[{ae, aebc}, Table[{u@x, guess@x}, {x, grid}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1418.56, Null} *)
solfunc = ListInterpolation[solrule[[All, -1]], grid];
Plot[solfunc@x, {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The right half of the solution slightly veers off the analytic solution, but I think it's not too bad. Tackling `points`, `difforder`, etc. may improve the result, but I'd like to stop here.

## Remark

1. The `nint` i.e. calculation for the principal value is probably the bottleneck of my solution. I've simply lived with the combination of `ListInterpolation` and `NIntegrate`, because I know nothing about numeric calculation of principal value.
2. It's lucky that `FindRoot` (almost) manages to find the desired result under such a casual initial guess `guess[x_] = 0` in this case, but do remember looking for proper initial guess for nonlinear BVP can be painful. Just search in this site, we already have dozens of examples.
3. The original problem you want to solve i.e. nonlinear eigenvalue problem is even harder, so, grit your teeth. Another example I can remember at the moment: [NDSolve eigenvalue problem of bound state](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164218/1871)

---

As to the test for $u(x)=\text{sech}(x)$ in the question, the grid chosen by OP turns out to be too coarse. After adjusting the parameters to `L = 7; points = 50;`, a pretty good result is obtained after `973.142` seconds. (Actually `L = 7; points = 25` is good enough, and the corresponding timing is `127.755`. )

Comment: just back to my computer. I appreciate your effort very much! Please give me a few days to understand your idea, test on my real problem, and wait for potential improvement or answer from someone. I will accept one later.

Comment: @jsxs Feel free to wait for better answers :) .

Comment: Great! your idea is basically for the validation of a non-trivial solution of an inhomogeneous ODE via an "inverse problem". In other words, specify an analytic special solution then determine the inhomogeneous function via `rhsfunc = ListInterpolation[...]`, then feed `rhsfunc` back to the ODE to (**inversely**) search the special solution iteratively with `FindRoot`. Am I right?

Comment: @jsxs Yes, exactly.

Comment: when solving the original homogeneous BVP with `eq =... == 0; bc={u[-L] == 0, u[L] == 0, u'[-L] == 0, u'[L] == 0}`; only the trival solution is found. Is it due to the initial guess? Another detailed issue, we have 4 b.c.s, thus 4 discrete b.c.s should be removed from both end, but `odebc = ptoafunc@newbc` not do this. Is it proper? Thank you!

Comment: 1. Yes. If you're sure non-trivial solution exists, better initial guess should be given. 2. The 4 equations have been removed from `ptoafunc@neweq`.

Comment: @jsxs No, and you need to put more effort in understanding the basic of FDM.

Comment: could you please review my update following your answer, which is a testing case. Thank you so much!

Comment: @jsxs I've rejected the edit because I think it's better to add it as a comment or a edit to the body of your question. As to the b.c., notice my definition for `newbc` is `With[{lhs = {u[-L] == 0, u[L] == 0, u'[-L] == 0, u'[L] == 0}[[All, 1]]}, 
    lhs == (lhs /. u -> Function[x, Sin[Pi x/L]]) // Thread]`. Just execute it and observe.

Comment: sorry to bother you @xzczd. Now I understand it. And let me add it in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94141/discussion-between-xzczd-and-jsxs).

Comment: The combination of `NIntegrate` and `Interpolation` makes the code very slow, for example, via the function `nint[u : {__?NumericQ}, x_] := With[{func = ListInterpolation[u, {domain}]},  NIntegrate[func[s]*Cot[(π (x - s))/(2 L)], {s, -L, x, L},...]`. What if we don't use `Interpolation`? Is it possible to avoid using the Interpolation?

Comment: @jsxs Sadly as mentioned in 1st remark, I'm not aware of any better method for calculating principal value numerically.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a perfect answer, but I will post it for reference.

I imposed boundary conditions according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_boundary_conditions), and tried to solve it while changing the velocity at $x=-L$.
First of all, since it takes time to integrate Cot [x], this function is approximated by splines.

```
L = 20;
cot = Interpolation[
   If[Element[#2, Reals], {#1, #2}, Nothing] & @@ # & /@ 
    Table[{x, Cot[x]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.01}]];

int[func_, x_] := 
  Fold[(#1 + (1/(2*L))*func'''[#2]*cot[(\[Pi]*(x - #2))/(2*L)]) &, 0, 
   Range[-L, L, 0.1]];
```

Next, sampling points uniformly and approximate the solution `u[x]`
(function approximation by hermite polynomial)

```
u = Interpolation[Table[{i, v[i]}, {i, -L, L, 1}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 4];
```

In this way, we convert the PDE into the optimization problem solving for the parameter `v[i]`,which minimize $L^2$ norm.

Next we define the loss function,
here,L^2 norm + penalty for boundary conditions.

```
loss[cf_?VectorQ][var_][speed_] :=
 Block[{L = 20, penalty = 10000, 
   rule = Thread[Rule[var, cf]]},
  ff = u /. rule;(*insert params*);
  (*b.c.s*);
  cnds = {ff[-L], ff[L] - ff[-L], ff'[-L] - speed, ff'[L] - ff'[-L], 
    ff''[L] - ff''[-L], ff'''[L] - ff'''[-L], ff''''[L] - ff''''[-L]};

  (*L2 norm and penalty*)
  Fold[(#1 + 
       Power[-ff'[#2] + ff[#2]*ff'[#2] + ff''[#2] + ff'''[#2] + 
         ff''''[#2] + 1/(2*L)*int[ff, #2], 2]) &, 0, 
    Range[-L, L, 1]] + Fold[#1 + penalty*Power[#2, 2] &, 0, cnds]]
```

Then use NMinimize to find the parameter `v[i]` that minimizes the loss function.

```
var = Table[v[i], {i, -20, 20, 1}];
answers = Table[
   sol = Last@
     NMinimize[loss[var][var][speed], var, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"];
   u[x] /. sol, {speed, Range[-1, 1, 0.1]}];
```

```
Animate[
 Dynamic@Plot[answers[[m]], {x, -20, 20}, 
   PlotLabel -> "u'[-L]=" <> ToString[((m/10) - 1.1)]], {m, 1, 21, 1}]
```

This is the solution we found.

[image]

From here onwards I need to understand the problem itself, so I'll leave it.
I think [xzdczd's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199077/61541) is the best.

---

For comments)
3) For loss function,
I used L^2 norm $||f||_2^2$ for the part of `differential equation`
 and **penalty terms** for the part of `boundary condition.`

In normal setting,
I have to increase the coefficient of that term,`100000`,[every iteration,like 10x times per iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method#Example).
but this problem needs a lot time to calcutation for one time,
so instead of update the number,I just set the big number.

if we have a true solution,the term converge to 0,so no matter how large the coffieicient,it is no problem.
that is my opinion.
(yes,my heurstics)

Comment: My personal experience is, `NMinimze`, `FindMinimum` etc. usually won't work well on nonlinear equation solving, `FindRoot` seems to be the only reasonable choice in most cases. (As we can see, `NMinimize` fails to find the trivial solution $u=0$ in this case. )

Comment: @Xminer I appreciate your effort very much! Please give me a few days to understand your idea, test on my real problem, and wait for potential improvement or answer from someone. I will accept one later.

Comment: @xzzczd you are correct.
However, this time NMinimize itself is not problem, but it seems I have to optimize where the knots/nodes are placed.

Comment: @jsxs the idea is pseudo-spectral method.I wanted to use it because I'm studying it now xp.  I think xzczd's answer is better.

Comment: @Xminer 1. I know something about pseudo-spectral, which approximates the solution on a periodic interval as a Fourier series $u(x)=\sum a_n e^{inx}$ where $a_n$ is the discrete Fourier coefficient, then the series will be truncated and the (space) derivatives can be evaluated by FFT. But I see no FFT in the code... which part is the core of pseudo-spectral?

Comment: @Xminer 2. I understood that `Block[{x,y,...},expr]` specifies `expr` to be evaluated with local values for the symbols x, y,... .  Here in `Block[{}, rule=...]`, we do not have symbols in `{}`. why? what is the subtlety?

Comment: @Xminer 3. Actually, i do not understand the piece of code `10000*Power[ff[-L], 2], 10000*Power[ff[L], 2], 10000*Power[ff'[-L], 2], 10000*Power[ff'[L], 2]`. To be specific, why we amplified the squared lhs of the BCs by 10000?

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer from what can be answered easily.

Comment: 2)
don't mind in {}
we can access the value outside `Block`.
you may want to read something like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/why-modules-with-no-variables)

Comment: 1)
the main idea of (Pseudo-)Spectral Method(sorry,I'm studying it now,and don't know the difference of the pseudo and normal one) is to approximate the true function by basis function.
or ,
My interpretation is to approximate the solution with a finite number of parameters (coefficients).
for example,we can use hermite polynomial(my case),[B-spline](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mma.5090),or even normal polynomial(x^n,n=1,2,....) [here](http://cdm.unimo.it/home/matematica/funaro.daniele/bube.htm)

Comment: 3) it's penalty for violating the boundary conditions. check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method) and my updated answer.

Comment: @Xminer thanks for the links! Btw how many RAM is required by the computation? It runs on my laptop (8G RAM) and manages to crash my system after ~20mins :-p

Comment: @jsxs my code has been improved to reduce memory load. try if you have free time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94147/discussion-between-xminer-and-jsxs).

Comment: @Xminer Thanks. what did you mean by "likelihood"?

Comment: I made a mistake,it is $L^2$ norm

Comment: @Xminer Without `Method -> "Spline"` in `Interpolation` for either `cot` and `u`, why did you believe it used Hermite polynomial to interpolate the data? Thank you :)

Comment: `interpolation` usually use hermite in mma. check the document for example.

Comment: @Xminer I have seen the help. Under the Method section, `Interpolation` has either `Method -> "Hermite"` or `Method -> "Spline"` without telling us which one is the default.

Comment: the words I chosen were wrong,sorry. click `InterpolatingFunction` objects like `Interplation[something]` of the example in the document `Interpolation` to check the methods used. Basically it should be hermite. Furthemore, since **spline method can not handle symbolic expressions**, there is no problem if it is not specified. Try `Interpolation[Table[{i, v[i]}, {i, 1, 5}], Method -> "Spline"]`

Comment: @Xminer now i see. Another small question: `cot` was approximated over $-10$ to $10$ but used in `int` from $-20$ to $20$. Is it problematic?

Comment: No. Since we divide the argument of `Cot` by `L=20`, the area for approximating `Cot` could be smaller.

Comment: I don't remember why I chose that area, but it should be randomly chosen.(and then checked by plotting `Cot`)

Comment: @Xminer, it should be safer if we use `L=20` in both places, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95667/discussion-between-xminer-and-jsxs).