# Should eigenvalues be ordered?

Tags: linear-algebra

When I run Eigensystem on a symmetric matrix, the list of eigenvalues (and so, the corresponding eigenvectors) is ordered by absolute values, which is quite bizarre (it does make sense if you view the symmetric eigenvalue problem as a special case of the general eigenvalue problem, where the eigenvalues are complex, so modulus is as good a way to order them as any). Has it always been thus? Is this considered a feature?

If one wants the "obvious" ordering, the following function works fine, but it's a bit annoying.

```
sortify[es_] := Module[{pp = FindPermutation[es[[1]]]}, PermutationReplace[#, pp] & /@ es]
```

**EDIT** My personal view is that this is a bug. Mathematica (or any system, for that matter) should always return things in canonical order, which happens to be the one coming from the total ordering on the real line for real numbers.

Comment: Closely related: [Find the eigenvector associated with the smallest eigenvalue, not smallest in magnitude](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44151/245)

Comment: @Karsten 7. thanks for formatting the code properly. How do you actually do that? :)

Comment: @Jens It is related in that my sortify[] actually answers the other guy's question...

Comment: @Jens I have just added an answer to that effect to the other question.

Comment: See [Code and Preformatted Text](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) or use the `{}` of the editor.

Comment: Don't you think this question should actually be entirely moved to the thread I linked? Of course I could also repeat my answer from there right here, but I don't think that's the right way to do it.

Comment: So, what do you think of the output of this: `Sort[{1, 2, 4, Sqrt[Pi]}]`? I think it's reasonable in a *symbolic* system.

Comment: @Jens I think that is a quite different question (though obviously opinions differ, and certainly I agree that it is related).

Comment: @MarkMcClure The confusion between syntax and semantics has always been a problem, and indicates the limitations of the term "canonical". However, if I see a list of actual numbers returned by the system, they should be in canonical order, and this should be something I can depend on. This implies, in particular, that complex numbers should be lexicographically ordered by real than imaginary part (otherwise, the canonical order on the complexes is inconsistent from that on the reals, as we see in this example).

Comment: than->then above.

Comment: I agree this question is different from the one I linked, so I decided to re-use my answer here.

Comment: Umm, the use of the "bug" word seems quite unmotivated. Also there is a dearth of actual code here to even understand the issue. For example, are we talking about exact or approximate matrices? Matrices with multiple eigenvalues (might matter, if input is approximate).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You are joking, right, about the "dearth of actual code"? The issue is that the list of real (floating point) numbers which represents the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix (with floating point entries) is NOT in the mathematica canonical ordering for such lists of floating point numbers. The word "bug" was there because I only ran into this in 10.0, and was not sure that this behavior has always been there. Since it seems that it has been, it is a design bug, not an implementation bug.

Comment: (1) No, not joking. Without input (a 2x2 or 3x3, say) or other description, I cannot tell whether you refer to exact or approximate input. Which matters. (2) It's not a bug, design or otherwise. It is simply an outcome you do not happen to like. Were it to change it would be inconsistent with the handling of the nonsymmetric case (unless we change that as well). Such a change might comprise a reasonable suggestion. But that's not the same thing as the current behavior being a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau My view is that while consistency might be the hobgoblin of small minds, it is a virtue in automated system, so its lack is a bug. It is not a question of "not happening to like it". (in any given case, it is not hard to fix things, as we see from the answers to this question, but having to waste time trying to figure out the exact output semantics [or, failing that, trying to kludge after the fact] is a BAD THING.

Comment: (1) Currently the ordering or eigenvalues between real-symmetric and general cases is consistent. If we change the latter case, e.g. to the ordering you indicate, they would become inconsistent. (2) The term "fix" is out of place since it isn't at present broken. (3) The documentation states: "If they are numeric, eigenvalues are sorted in order of decreasing absolute value." What part of the semantics takes figuring out?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau These are all fair points, but the general mathematica principle is that the output is given the user sorted in canonical order. The canonical order for real numbers is increasing. The canonical order for complex number appears to be lexicographic with the real part sorted first [I have just tried] - this is obviously the most natural order compatible with the standard ordering on the reals. Eigensystem[] does not use the canonical order for either real or complex numbers. Therefore, this is a bug, IM(not so)HO.

Comment: As is often said of eigenvalues, Cauchy distributions, and [other things with large tails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvrGIxmv7wY), "size does matter".

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, of course it matters, but consistency matters even more.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156035/primes-approximated-by-eigenvalues

Answer (score 11):

The order of eigenvalues is the most convenient order for the algorithm, which find these eigenvalues. You can always order them as you want very simply

```
a = # + #\[Transpose] &@RandomReal[1, {10, 10}];
{ε, ψ} = Eigensystem[a];
{ε, ψ} = {ε[[#]], ψ[[#]]} &@ Ordering[ε];
```

Furthermore, the eigenvalues can be complex for non-Hermitian matrices. There is no native order of complex values.

Comment: The way you are suggesting is a somewhat more elegant variant of what I am suggesting in the question, but the lexicographic ordering of complex numbers is a natural extension of the "usual" ordering of real numbers.

Comment: @IgorRivin It is not just more elegant. It works much faster then `FindPermutation` and about 10% faster then Jens's solution.

Comment: @ybeltukov Yes indeed, this is very nice and captures the spirit of what Igor was suggesting (+1).

Answer (score 3):

As I mention in the [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44153/245), you can always translate the spectrum of the matrix by the Hilbert-Schmidt norm to be certain that *Mathematica*'s ordering of the eigenvalues will coincide with the natural order on the real line. For a large matrix, this is more efficient that `FindPermutations`.

**Edit**

Here is an implementation of the shift approach:

```
Clear[sortedEigensystem];
sortedEigensystem[
   matrix_?MatrixQ] :=
  (Eigensystem[
       matrix - # IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[matrix]]] + {#, 0}) &@
   Norm[Flatten[matrix]];
```

Responding to the comment, as a test, consider the matrix

```
d = (# + Transpose@#) &@N@RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {2000, 2000}];
AbsoluteTiming[eigs = sortedEigensystem[d];]

(* ==> {2.220592, Null} *)
```

On the other hand, trying the approach in the question for the large matrix `d` runs for a very long time and ultimately **fails** to produce an ordered list of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

**Edit 2**

When doing **machine arithmetic** computations, it's worth keeping in mind that `Eigensystem` is not the only normal form that sorts eigenvalues according to absolute value. Another function that does the same thing is `JordanDecomposition`. But its output is not in the same form as `Eigensystem`. The eigenvalues appear on the diagonal of a generally upper-triangular matrix in block form. In order to sort the output consistently, one would have to sort not only these blocks but also find the corresponding similarity transformation matrix.

On the other hand, the approach based on shifting the spectrum can be directly applied to this normal form as well:

```
Clear[sortedJordanDecomposition];
sortedJordanDecomposition[
   matrix_?MatrixQ] := (JordanDecomposition[matrix - #] + {0, #}) &[
   Norm[Flatten[matrix]] IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[matrix]]];

{s, j} = sortedJordanDecomposition[d];

Diagonal[j] == eigs[[1]]

(* ==> True *)
```

The last line shows that the Jordan blocks are now automatically sorted the same way as for `orderedEigensystem` above.

Comment: Actually, I disagree with this. for an $n\times n$ matrix, computing the norm is $O(n^2),$ finding the permutation is $O(n \log n).$ But, more importantly, both these are insignificant compared to the cost of actually computing the eigensystem.

Comment: I checked the timings for the example from the linked question. See my update.

Comment: Interesting! The natural question is why the FindPermutation[] thing fails (looks like a bug to me), but in the meantime I agree that yours is the way to go (since it actually works...)

Comment: @IgorRivin Yes - it certainly shouldn't fail without warning in your approach. Maybe it's a memory issue.

Comment: In principle my approach should also work for `JordanDecomposition`, but I have to verify how the latter orders its Jordan blocks under different conditions. This may be an advantage of my approach, in that it doesn't need different sorting strategies for different normal forms.

Comment: Yes, that's true, with the proviso that your approach requires thinking for the different normal forms (in that you might need to fudge in a different way [that is, different size of fudge summand, or some completely different strategy]. )

Comment: As for why FindPermutation[] does not work, if I were to implement it, I would simply sort, and keep track of the transpositions, then multiply them together backwards. This should take very little [linear] memory, and $O(n \log n)$ time, and should actually be faster than @ybeltukov's method (because all this would be happening in the C layer). So, something is weird [but we knew that].

Comment: Agreed about the sorting bug. I added my version of `JordanDecomposition` just for completeness. In fact, thinking of that decomposition, it occurred to me that sorting by absolute value as Mathematica does could be more natural when testing convergence of matrix power series... but it's not a 100% justification.