# Sort eigenvectors of a list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra

I have a list of matrices and want to obtain a list of eigenvectors and eigenvalues for each matrix, both sorted by the size of the eigenvalue. If I write `system={eigenvalues, eigenvectors}`, where `eigenvalues` is a list of lists of eigenvalues for each of the matrices, I would like to sort the eigenvectors by writing

```
Map[Sort[#, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]]] &, Transpose[system]]
```

of some sort, but this does nothing useful.

Comment: Please provide `system`. Looks like you got some surplus `&` there as well.

Comment: @ joe8: the function Eigensystem[m] gives you {List of eigenvectors, List of Eigenvalues}. You can use Norm[] to check the order of the eigenvectors. As far as I have seen in some examples they are ordered in descending order.

Comment: @ybeltukov: I meant to sort by the size of the eigenvalue; corrected my mistake.

Comment: @joe8 OK, now it is well posed problem. Do [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59188/4678) answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > ```
> > Ordering[Norm /@ Last @ N[Eigensystem[system]]];
> > ```

gives you the ordering by norm. You can apply this on your eigenvalues and eigenvectors, e.g.

> > ```
> > Eigenvectors[system][[%]]
> > ```

**EDIT**

To apply this on a list of matrices:

> > ```
> > (# &@Ordering[Norm /@ N[#]]) & /@ Eigenvectors[#] & /@ {mat1,mat2,...,matn}
> > ```

Comment: this solutions seems to work for a single matrix, but not for a list of several matrices. I am unable to generalize it to my problem.

Comment: I guess the questions then is whether Ordering can be used on sublists only.

Comment: That should not be a huge problem; you can wrap the above in a function and then apply that to your list of matrices, but before I update my answer, please clarify if you want to sort the eigenvectors per matrix, or the matrixes based on their eigenvector norms. If the latter, can I assume sorting is based on largest eigenvector norm?

Comment: I want to sort per matrix.

Comment: updated to accommodate per matrix sorting.

Comment: I modified this to use it to sort by size of eigenvalue, as originally intended. Passing the output of `Ordering` to `Part`, as in `Eigenvectors[system][[%]]` requires something like `MapThread[Part[#1, #2] &, {eigenvectors, %}]`. Many thanks!