# How to obtain the eigenvector corresponding to the minimal eigenvalue of a generailzed eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have the following input

---

a = Import["d:\am.txt", "Table"];

b = Import["d:\bm.txt", "Table"];

c = Eigenvalues[N[{a, b}, 5]];

Min[c]

---

where am.txt is

3.0   2.0

2.0   3.0

bm.txt is

1.0   0.8

0.8   1.0

Mathematica gives me
2.77778

My question is, how to obtain the eigenvector correspond to this eigenvalue? I can figure it out by hand for 2*2 problem. But for general case, it is not so simple..

Comment: You may use `Eigensystem` to get the eigenvalues together with their corresponding eigenvectors. For example, `Eigensystem[N[{a, b}, 5], -1]` for the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: Good thing I updated the window; almost posted same a minute later.

Comment: @Oleksandr R The tricky point is, Eigensystem choose the smallest absolute of eigenvalues, Min choose the smallest eigenvalue. If there are -1.0 and 0.1 two eigenvalues, Eigensystem will choose 0.1, while Min choose -1.0 (this is what I want)

Comment: Okay, then in that case perhaps you have to use `Eigensystem` without the second argument and retrieve all eigenvalues/vectors, and pick the one you want.

Comment: If there are thousands eigenvalues and eigenvectors, I feel it is quite tedious to pick up the right one from the screen...

Comment: If the matrix is Hermitian so all real eigenvalues, then you can do an estimate for the maximal eigenvalue norm, call it `m`, and use `Eigensystem[mat-IdentityMatrix[Length[mat]]*m, 1]`. Note that we now are taking the largest, not smallest.

Comment: Re duplicate, I think the correct one is [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44151/find-the-eigenvector-associated-with-the-smallest-eigenvalue-not-smallest-in-ma) (which is referenced from the one provided).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I think this prescription works for eigenvalue problem Ac= \lambda c, but necessarily for generalized eigenvalue problem Ac= \lambda B c..., if I am not mistaken...