# Checking if a symbolic matrix is positive semi-definite

Tags: symbolic, linear-algebra

As far as I can tell, there is no way to tell the builtin `PositiveSemidefiniteQ` about assumptions on symbols.

For example, the matrix

```
{{1,0,0,Sqrt[1-p]}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,p,0}, {Sqrt[1-p],0,0,1-p}}
```

has eigenvalues `{0,0,2-p,p}` and is therefore positive semi-definite whenever `0<=p<=2`, but `PositiveSemidefiniteQ` always returns `False`.

Is checking the non-negativity of the eigenvalues with `$Assumptions` a good way to test for this? Or would it be better to do something like row-reduction? There are a bunch of algorithms answering [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37362/check-if-a-matrix-is-positive-semidefinite), but I don't know which ones translate best to symbolics.

Edits:

1. The scope section of the documentation for `PositiveSemidefiniteQ` says "The test returns `False` unless it is true for all possible complex values of symbolic parameters")
2. For clarification, I mean my questions exactly as stated above. To paraphrase, what is the best way to check for the positive semi-definite condition of a symbolic matrix allowing for symbol assumptions? This question is given in the context that, in the numeric case, checking eigenvalue signs is not the best way.

Comment: "I am therefore interested in an implementation that allows for assumptions." <--  I would recommend rewriting your question, including this bit of information I found, and asking specifically about such an implementation.  I deleted my answer to give room for new ones.  For reference, my answer pointed at the documentation of PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ, Examples -> Scope.

Answer (score 7):

One way is shown below. Alternatives include using `Simplify` with `Assumptions`, again on testing that the eigenvalues are nonnegative.

```
Resolve[
 ForAll[p, 0 <= p <= 2, 
  And @@ Thread[
    Eigenvalues[{{1, 0, 0, Sqrt[1 - p]}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, p, 
        0}, {Sqrt[1 - p], 0, 0, 1 - p}}] >= 0]]]

(* Out[9]= True *)
```