# Checking range of values of a symbol for which a matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

Very much related to this question:

[Checking if a symbolic matrix is positive semi-definite](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80002/checking-if-a-symbolic-matrix-is-positive-semi-definite)

Is there a way to tell for which values of symbols a matrix is positive definite? For instance if `M = {{a,0}, {0,b}}` the function should look like `rangePositiveDefiniteQ[M, {a,b}]` and return `{a>0 && b>0}`. I have a feeling this is extremely computationally expensive and unfeasible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For not too difficult problems, you could use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) + [`Eigenvalues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues):

```
positiveDefiniteQ[m_, v_] := Reduce[
    Thread[Eigenvalues[m] > 0],
    v,
    Reals
]
```

Your example:

```
positiveSemiDefiniteQ[{{a, 0}, {0, b}}, {a, b}]
```

> a > 0 && b > 0

For the example in the linked question, define `positiveSemiDefiniteQ`:

```
positiveSemiDefiniteQ[m_, v_] := Reduce[
    Thread[Eigenvalues[m] >= 0],
    v,
    Reals
]
```

Then:

```
positiveSemiDefiniteQ[
    {{1,0,0,Sqrt[1-p]},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,p,0},{Sqrt[1-p],0,0,1-p}},
    p
]
```

> 0 <= p <= 2